# 7.x MODERN treegrid - nodecollapse/nodeexpand events : null row parameter

Tags: extjs, extjs7

Ext.grid.cell.Tree `collapse` and `expand` method should fire `nodecollapse` and `nodeexpand` with the Ext.grid.Row that was collapsed/expanded

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/modern/Ext.grid.Tree.html#event-nodecollapse

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/modern/Ext.grid.Tree.html#event-nodeexpand

Instead of that, we are getting a null parameter

Answer (score 0):

Should override both methods and replace `me.parent` with `me.row`

```
Ext.define('Override.grid.cell.Tree', {
  override: 'Ext.grid.cell.Tree',
  collapse: function() {
      var me = this;
      me.getGrid()
          .fireEventedAction('nodecollapse', [/*me.parent*/ me.row, me.getRecord(), 'collapse'], 'doToggle', me);
  },
  expand: function() {
      ...
      tree.fireEventedAction('nodeexpand', [/*me.parent*/ me.row, record, 'expand'], 'doToggle', me);
      ...
  }
```

**Related support issue : EXTJS-29424**